How to provide a static domain for collecting the secondary branch in Cloudflare Pages?
Currently, I handle new commits to the dev branch by the configuration described below. So, I expect that every commit pushed to the main-Test branch appears as a preview deployment since is not pushed to the main branch. Thus, I'm unable to use same subdomain for test environment and forced to use 80ef80df.my-project.pages.dev-like subdomain which is regenerated for each new publish.
I'm looking for a way to automatically publish each version appeared on my main-Test branch on the same subdomain of my domain. Is there ways to achieve it?
Here's my current GitHub Actions workflow:
name: ci staging

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main-Test

jobs:
  build-test-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      ...
      - name: Publish
        uses: cloudflare/pages-action@1
        with:
          apiToken: ${{ secrets.CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN }}
          accountId: ${{ secrets.CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT_ID }}
          projectName: test-izde-vendor
          directory: dist

